# Using $rename in MongoDB for an item inside an array of objects

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, mongodb

Consider the following MongoDB collection of a few thousand Objects:

```
{
_id: ObjectId("xxx") 
FM_ID: "123" 
Meter_Readings: Array
  0: Object
   Date: 2011-10-07 
   Begin_Read: true
   Reading: 652
  1: Object
   Date: 2018-10-01 
   Begin_Reading: true
   Reading: 851
}
```

The wrong key was entered for 2018 into the array and needs to be renamed to "Begin_Read". I have a list using another aggregate of all the objects that have the incorrect key. The objects within the array don't have an _id value, so are hard to select. I was thinking I could iterate through the collection and find the array index of the errored Readings and using the _id of the object to perform the `$rename` on the key.

I am trying to get the index of the array, but cannot seem to select it correctly. The following aggregate is what I have:

```
[
{
    '$match': {
        '_id': ObjectId('xxx')
    }
}, {
    '$project': {
        'index': {
            '$indexOfArray': [
                '$Meter_Readings', {
                    '$eq': [
                        '$Meter_Readings.Begin_Reading', True
                    ]
                 }
             ]
          }
        }
    }
]
```

Its result is always -1 which I think means my expression must be wrong as the expected result would be 1.

I'm using Python for this script (can use javascript as well), if there is a better way to do this (maybe a filter?), I'm open to alternatives, just what I've come up with.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this myself. I was close with the aggregate but needed to look at a different field for some reason that one did not work:

```
{
 '$project': {
   'index': {
      '$indexOfArray': [
          '$Meter_Readings.Water_Year', 2018
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
```

What I did learn was the to find an object within an array you can just reference it in the array identifier in the `$indexOfArray` method. I hope that might help someone else.